# simple application with only main class doesn't see logback.xml

Tags: java, logging, logback, log-level

My project structure:

[image]

As you can see I tried to put logback.xml everywhere.

I want to setup info log level for root logger.

**logback.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Send logs to both console and file audit -->
    <logger name="kafka_test" level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>


</configuration>
```

I have following code:

```
public class Consumer {
    private static final String name = "consumer_1";

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        logger.debug("Consumer {} started", name);
        ...
```

And it prints

```
17:51:45.096 [main] DEBUG kafka_test.Consumer - Consumer consumer_1 started
```

into console.

What do I wrong?

### P.S.

I tried to print:

```
    System.out.println(Consumer.class.getClassLoader().getResource("kafka_test/Consumer.class"));
```

It prints:

```
file:/D:/work/kafka_samples/out/production/classes/kafka_test/Consumer.class
```

I put `logback.xml` into

```
D:\work\kafka_samples\out\production\classes\kafka_test
```

But it still doesn't work

### Solution:

I've put `logback.xml` into

```
D:\work\kafka_samples\out\production\classes
```

Comment: put logback.xml in the runtime classpath.  The package in which the class resides is not the runtime classpath.

Comment: @DwB can you clarify what means 'runtime classpath' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put it at the top-level of your classpath. The standard location for a maven/gradle project would be in `src/main/resources`. Gradle/maven will include that resources directory on your classpath (and most IDEs will understand that too).

Comment: Can you provide exact folder path?

Comment: kafka_samples/src/main/resources